# A problem on the divisibility of central binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, conjectures, advice

Erdos proved that,
$$\gcd\left(\binom{2n}{n},pq\right)=1$$
For infinitely many $n\in\mathbf{N}$.
Where $p,q$ are primes.
Later the following idea was conjectured by Graham,
That,
$$\gcd\left(\binom{2n}{n},105\right)=1$$ for infinitely many $n$

What are recent advances made towards the problem?

Here is a [reference](https://eudml.org/doc/207133).

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A030979, you can find some references there.